# Print and join elements of a Json with Python

Tags: python, json

I have a json and I need to create a list of list like:

```
lista = [['334507', 'XXX', '334507', 36.07, 3985499.0],
['271018','YYY', '271007', 23.11, 1335150.0]]

all_sites = {
    u'displayValue': {
        u'siteId': {u'334507': u'XXX', u'271018': u'YYY'}
    },
    u'rows': [[u'334507', 36.07, 3985499.0],
              [u'271018', 23.11, 1335150.0]],
    u'alert': None,
    u'columns': [u'siteId', u'revenue', u'paidImpressions'],
    u'currency': u'USD'

}
```

I tried with something like this:

```
sites = all_sites['displayValue']['siteId'].items()
sites_data = all_sites['rows']

data = []

for item in sites:
    data.append(list(item))

for item in sites_data:
    data.append(item)
```

But how can I merge the list with the first item of the list??

Comment: Well for starters `all_sites['displayValue']['siteId']` is of type dictionary and to access both key and value you need to use `for key,value in all_sites['displayValue']['siteId'].items()`. But your data is stored in another variable: `all_sites['displayValue']['rows']`. Your attempt to fetch all data is incomplete.

Comment: How do you link 271018 and 271007?

Comment: I guess, your `json_` variable should've been called `all_sites`.

Comment: @jpp nicely spotted. Can be a typo ofc.

Comment: It'll be inefficient to find the specific index in the array calls rows where your siteId exists. I would recommend making `rows` a dictionary instead where the key would be your siteId. Otherwise, you'd have to iterate though all indices until you find the index where the element (sub-array) has your siteId as the first index.

Comment: I edited the question. @AntonvBR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just giving what you asked for :)

```
[[k,v]+all_sites['rows'][i] for i, (k,v) in enumerate(all_sites['displayValue']['siteId'].items())]
```

---

First, iterate over the siteId:

```
>>> [t for t in all_sites['displayValue']['siteId'].items()]
[('334507', 'XXX'), ('271018', 'YYY')]
```

Now, you know that it will give you a tuple in t, which you might replace as:

```
>>> [[k,v] for k,v in all_sites['displayValue']['siteId'].items()]
[['334507', 'XXX'], ['271018', 'YYY']]
```

Now, the other items are in the "rows" key, but you need to know the row's index. One way of knowing the index of each (k,v) tuple is:

```
>>> [[k,v]+[i] for i, (k,v) in enumerate(all_sites['displayValue']['siteId'].items())]
[['334507', 'XXX', 0], ['271018', 'YYY', 1]]
```

See that it merges the list [k,v] with the list [i]. Now, all you have to do is take the row you are interested for each index:

```
>>> [[k,v]+all_sites['rows'][i] for i, (k,v) in enumerate(all_sites['displayValue']['siteId'].items())]
[['334507', 'XXX', '334507', 36.07, 3985499.0],
 ['271018', 'YYY', '271018', 23.11, 1335150.0]]
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes that is what I need. Can you explain me how can you do the function??

Comment: sure, I'll improve it for clarity, glad it helped

Comment: I think Oluwafemi's answer bellow is a way smarter tough :)

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate the `siteId` field items. 
Then zip this with the list in the `rows` field.

Iterate over the zip and extend each `item` (note that item should be converted to a list before extending it) with its matching `row`.

```
siteid_items = json_['displayValue']['siteId'].items()
rows = json_["rows"]

result = list(
    list(item) + row
    for item, row in zip(siteid_items, rows)
)

print(result)

''' 
stdout:

[['334507', 'XXX', '334507', 36.07, 3985499.0],
['271018', 'YYY', '271018', 23.11, 1335150.0]]
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Below example may help you.

```
json_ = {u'displayValue': {u'siteId': {u'334507': u'XXX', u'271018': u'YYY'}},
     u'rows': [[u'334507', 36.07, 3985499.0], [u'271007', 23.11, 1335150.0]],
     u'alert': None,
     u'columns': [u'siteId', u'revenue', u'paidImpressions'],
     u'currency': u'USD'}

result = []
count = len(json_["displayValue"]["siteId"])

for element in range(count):
    item = list(json_["displayValue"]["siteId"].items()[element])+json_["rows"][element]
    result.append(item)

print result
```

Output:

```
[[u'334507', u'XXX', u'334507', 36.07, 3985499.0], [u'271018', u'YYY', u'271007', 23.11, 1335150.0]]
```